# Adding User to Chef via Chef Server API

Tags: php, http, chef-infra

I am attempting to create a user on my Chef Server through the Chef Server API. I am currently using a PHP wrapper for the API interface which can be found [here](https://github.com/jenssegers/php-chef).

I understand that in order to create a user using the API, you must provide the pivotal.pem file as well as the pivotal username.

Here is a snippet of my PHP code that I am using:

```
// ENVIRONMENT VARIABLES
// The URL for the Chef Server
$server  = "mycompany.com";
// The name used when authenticating
$client  = 'pivotal';
// The location of the file which contains the client key
$key     = "../../../pivotal.pem";
// The version of the Chef Server API that is being used
$version = "12.0.2";

// Create a Chef object
$chef = new Chef($server, $client, $key, $version);

// API Request
$createUserRequest = array("name"=>$displayName, "display_name"=>$displayName, "email"=>$emailAddress, "password"=>$password);
$createUserRequest = json_encode($createUserRequest);

$chef->post('/users/', $createUserRequest);
```

Here is the reponse that I receive from the server:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'Invalid signature for user or client 'pivotal'' in C:\Workspace\SA_SSAF\app\plugin\CHEF\Chef PHP\src\Jenssegers\Chef\Chef.php:187
Stack trace:
#0 C:\..\..\app\plugin\CHEF\Chef PHP\src\Jenssegers\Chef\Chef.php(70): Jenssegers\Chef\Chef->api('/users/', 'POST', '{"name":"entra"...')
#1 C:\..\..\app\plugin\CHEF\controller\chefEnrollUser.php(55): Jenssegers\Chef\Chef->post('/users/', '{"name":"entra"...')
#2 {main}
  thrown in C:\..\..\app\plugin\CHEF\Chef PHP\src\Jenssegers\Chef\Chef.php on line 187
```

If I try and perform a GET request using the same configuration, I receive a successful response.

Any clues as to why something like this may be happening?

Thanks

Comment: Read again the API, posting to `/users` accept no parameters (and it returns the url for the current uer profile). If you want to create a user you have to  post to `/users/NAME` in your case: `$chef->post("/users/".$displayname, $createUserRequest);` should do. And stop trying to compare GET and POST request, it's like comparing reading a document and writing it, they serve different purpose and don't accept the sames parameters.

Comment: @Tensibai, thanks for the clarification. I continue to receive a **405 - Method Not Allowed** response from the server despite passing in the required parameters as you've mentioned

Comment: Then  ask for the chef-server logs (`chef-server-ctl tail` while you're sending the request) It should give you something more. Try removing the json_encode call, IIRc the library already take care of this, your problem may be a double json encoding finally.